# Counting the values in a single column

Tags: r

I'm using the sqldf package in R and am trying to find the count of values which are 1 and 2 in a single column. My data looks like:

```
> head(d)
       bid status
1  201-300      1
2  201-300      1
3 901-1000      2
4  601-700      1
5  801-900      1
6  801-900      2
```

I am trying to find the count of status when it's equal to 1 and the count of status when it's equal to 2, and then have them in two separate columns.

So using the sqldf package in R, I ran the following code:

```
sqldf("SELECT bid, SUM(IF(status='2', 1,0)) AS 'won', SUM(IF(status='1', 1,0)) AS 'lost', COUNT(bid) FROM d GROUP BY bid")
```

However, I get the following error message.

```
Error in sqliteExecStatement(con, statement, bind.data) : 
  RS-DBI driver: (error in statement: no such function: IF)
```

Is this not possible with the sqldf package?
Is there a way to get the desired results with another sql command in R? (or with plyr, reshape, or any other tool in R)

Comment: Your query is a valid mysql query. is this question about mysql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you said you could be interested in a `plyr` based solution, I can give that:

```
ddply(d, .(bid), summarise, won = sum(status==2), 
                            lost = sum(status==1), count = length(bid))
```

Comment: + 1 Thanks! sql syntax has always been more intuitive for me, but I like this solution and will have to learn more about plyr.

Answer (score 4):

The `IF` is afaik a `MySQL` specific syntax while the error indicates you are talking to a `SQLite` database.

You should replace the `IF` with a `CASE` which would work on all DMBS's that are ANSI SQL-92 compliant.

```
SELECT  bid
        , SUM(CASE WHEN status = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS won
        , SUM(CASE WHEN status = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS lost
FROM    d
GROUP BY
        bid
```

Answer (score 2):

The normal SQL for this would be to use `CASE` and `SUM` - I don't do MySQL but I'm assuming this should be valid syntax:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN Status = '2' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'won',
       SUM(CASE WHEN Status = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'lost',
...
```

Answer (score 2):

**Edit: the question was tagged mysql but I am not sure is this is the case**

Have a look at [MySQL Control Flow Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html). You could use the `IF` construct (MySQL specific) or `CASE WHEN` (ANSI compatible) operator:

```
SELECT
bid,
SUM(IF(status = 2, 1, 0)) AS `won`,
SUM(IF(status = 1, 1, 0)) AS `lost`,
COUNT(bid)
FROM d
GROUP BY bid


SELECT
bid,
SUM(CASE status WHEN 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `won`,
SUM(CASE status WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `lost`,
COUNT(bid)
FROM d
GROUP BY bid
```

Comment: +1 Now I'd like to think that *great minds think alike* <vbg>

Answer (score 1):

`if` is not valid [SQLite syntax](http://pages.citebite.com/h2h1h2t3y9hbd). Try this:

```
> sqldf("select bid, sum(status=1) lost, sum(status=2) won, count(*) count 
+ from d group by bid")
       bid lost won count
1  201-300    2   0     2
2  601-700    1   0     1
3  801-900    1   1     2
4 901-1000    0   1     1
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
select count(bid) as 'bid_status_1' from d where bid_status = 1 union select count(bid) as 'bid_status_2'from d where bid_status = 2
```

Comment: @Tuong - this would return 2 records instead of one. It could be made to work if you add a dummy column, wrap this in a subselect, group on it and take care of the NULL's.

Comment: A left right inner join would seem more appropriate than a union, but still would be missing a count column.